# fixed div width 100%, exceeds body width of 960px

Tags: html, css

I have a body width of 960px, but when I set the width of the fixed header div to 100% it exceed the 960px body width and has a width of 1349px.

How do I get the 100% to match the 960px body width ?

HTML

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="banner">
    <div class="logo">
         <h1>CML International</h1>
    </div>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

CSS

```
/* FONTS
============================*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700);



/* BODY
============================*/
* {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  width: 960px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}



/* BANNER
============================*/
.head {
  width: 960px;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #111;
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo,
.navigation { 
  position: absolute;
}

.logo,
.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo {
  left: 20px;
  top: 21.5px;
}

.logo h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navigation {
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 31px;
}

.navigation li {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li a,
.logo {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fixed` position will take 100% width of the `html` tag in this case. You need to use pixel size for this case. Also, for the banner to stay aligned to center, use `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto`

Answer (score 0):

Why give the body the 960px? Define an div i.e. id="wrapper" for the content section an give them the width of 960px!?

```
<body>
    <header>
        ...
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper" style="width:960px; etc">
        // content here
    </div>
</body>
```